# How to disable Shift + Arrow keys selection in C++ console (in code)

Tags: c++, windows, console, keyboard

I'm trying to make an ASCII engine. I use shift for movement and when I combine it with arrow keys the text gets selected and the program pauses until I deselect manually.

How can I disable this in code? I can probably disable it in the Console setting, however, I want to do it automatically in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lookup `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` in [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).